geepack:: geeglm Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]): contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
I'm using the geeglm() command to fit a logistic regression model via GEE, intending to incorporate an unstructured correlation matrix to capture within-participant correlations (for subjects with two eligible eyes). However, I've encountered errors whenever I attempt to specify the correlation structure as unstructured. Instead, when I set the corstr argument to "exchangeable", the code runs without issue. Since the cluster size is at most 2, both the exchangeable and unstructured correlation structures should yield the same results, requiring estimation of only one alpha. Hence, I'm puzzled as to why one works while the other doesn't.
Please see below example:
library(tidyverse)

library(geepack)

example <- structure(list(patient = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 
16L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 
25L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 
35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 38L, 39L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 43L, 
44L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "9", "11", "12", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "25", 
"27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", 
"40", "42", "45", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", 
"55", "56", "57", "59", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", 
"68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "74", "75", "76", "78", "80", "81", 
"82", "83", "86", "87", "89", "90", "91", "92", "93", "94", "95", 
"99", "100", "101", "102", "103", "104", "105", "107", "108", 
"109", "110", "111", "113", "114", "116", "117", "118", "120", 
"122", "123", "124", "125", "128", "129", "130", "131", "133", 
"134", "136", "137", "139", "140", "141", "143", "144", "145", 
"146", "150", "153", "154", "155", "157", "158", "159", "160", 
"161", "163", "164", "165", "166", "167", "168", "169", "170", 
"173", "174", "175", "176", "177", "178", "181", "182", "183", 
"185", "190", "192", "193", "195", "196", "198", "199", "200", 
"201", "202", "203", "204", "205", "206", "207", "208", "209", 
"210", "212", "213", "214", "215", "216", "217", "218", "219", 
"220", "221", "224", "225", "229", "230", "231", "233", "234", 
"235", "236", "237", "238", "239", "241", "242", "243", "244", 
"245", "246", "247", "249", "251", "252", "253", "254", "255", 
"256", "257", "258", "260", "261", "262", "264", "266", "267", 
"268", "269", "270", "271", "272", "273", "274", "275", "276", 
"277", "278", "281", "282", "284", "285", "287", "288", "289", 
"290", "291", "292", "296", "297", "298", "299", "300", "301", 
"302", "304", "305", "307", "309", "310", "312", "313", "318", 
"320", "322", "323", "324", "325", "326", "327", "330", "331", 
"334", "335", "336", "337", "338", "343", "344", "345", "346", 
"347", "348", "351", "353", "356", "358", "359", "362", "363", 
"364", "365", "366", "367", "368", "370", "371", "373", "375", 
"376", "377", "380", "381", "382", "383", "384", "385", "386", 
"387", "388", "389", "390", "392", "393", "395", "396", "398", 
"402", "403", "404", "406", "407", "408", "409", "411", "412", 
"413", "414", "416", "417", "422", "423", "424", "425", "426", 
"427", "428", "430", "433", "434", "435", "436", "437", "439", 
"440", "441", "442", "443", "444", "445", "446", "447", "449", 
"451", "452", "453", "454", "457", "461", "465", "467", "468", 
"469", "471", "472", "473", "476", "479", "480", "484", "485", 
"486", "490", "493", "494", "500", "503", "507", "511", "514", 
"515", "516", "517", "518", "525", "526", "527", "530", "536", 
"537", "540", "541", "542", "543", "544", "548", "549", "553", 
"560", "562", "563", "564", "565", "569", "570", "575", "576", 
"580", "581", "582", "583", "584", "587", "588", "589", "590", 
"593", "595", "597", "598", "601", "604", "609", "613", "614", 
"623", "624", "629", "630", "632", "633", "634", "635", "636", 
"637", "639", "640", "641", "642", "643", "644", "645", "646", 
"648", "650", "653", "654", "657", "659", "660", "661", "665", 
"669", "670", "671", "674", "675", "677", "679", "680", "683", 
"684", "690", "691", "692", "693", "694", "699", "703", "705", 
"706", "707", "708", "709", "710", "711", "712", "713", "714", 
"716", "720", "721", "722", "726", "727", "729", "731", "733", 
"734", "736", "737", "741", "743", "745", "747", "748", "749", 
"751", "753", "754", "755", "756", "758", "759", "760", "761", 
"763", "764", "765", "768", "769", "770", "773", "775", "776", 
"777", "778", "779", "780", "782", "783", "784", "786", "787", 
"788", "789", "793", "794", "796", "797", "798", "799", "801", 
"803", "804", "805", "807", "808", "809", "810", "811", "813", 
"814", "817", "818", "821", "822", "823", "824", "825", "826", 
"827", "828", "830", "833", "834", "835", "838", "841", "842", 
"845", "846", "847", "848", "851", "853", "854", "855", "857", 
"859", "861", "864", "865", "868", "869", "870", "872", "873", 
"879", "883", "884", "888", "890", "891", "894", "898", "901", 
"903", "908", "909", "914", "915", "919", "920", "925", "927", 
"930", "931", "932", "933", "934", "938", "939", "940", "942", 
"944", "947", "949", "950", "951", "952", "953", "955", "957", 
"959", "960", "961", "963", "966", "970", "971", "976", "977", 
"978", "979", "981", "985", "986", "989", "991", "992", "998", 
"1000", "1001", "1002", "1003", "1004", "1006", "1011", "1012", 
"1013", "1014", "1016", "1018", "1019", "1024", "1026", "1027", 
"1028", "1029", "1030", "1031", "1032", "1034", "1035", "1036", 
"1037", "1038", "1040", "1041", "1042", "1043", "1047", "1049", 
"1050", "1051", "1054", "1055", "1056", "1057", "1059", "1060", 
"1061", "1062", "1064", "1065", "1067", "1068", "1071", "1072", 
"1077", "1080", "1081", "1082", "1084", "1086", "1088", "1089", 
"1091", "1094", "1098", "1100", "1111", "1112", "1118", "1119", 
"1120", "1129", "1139", "1145", "1155", "1161", "1167", "1176", 
"1178", "1181", "1184", "1185", "1188", "1190", "1192", "1196", 
"1197", "1199", "1200", "1201", "1206", "1209", "1211", "1225", 
"1229", "1231", "1234", "1235", "1236", "1238", "1239", "1240", 
"1241", "1242", "1243", "1245", "1247", "1250", "1252", "1253", 
"1254", "1255", "1256", "1258", "1260", "1261", "1265", "1271", 
"1272", "1273", "1274", "1275", "1276", "1279", "1281", "1285", 
"1287", "1288", "1290", "1291", "1296", "1302", "1304", "1306", 
"1308", "1310", "1311", "1313", "1314", "1315", "1319", "1326", 
"1337", "1341", "1343", "1346", "1348", "1352", "1353", "1358", 
"1360", "1362", "1365", "1366", "1367", "1368", "1369", "1370", 
"1371", "1372", "1375", "1380", "1382", "1385", "1386", "1392", 
"1393", "1394", "1395", "1396", "1399", "1408", "1411", "1413", 
"1415", "1416", "1421", "1422", "1423", "1425", "1431", "1433", 
"1436", "1439", "1440", "1441", "1443", "1444", "1460", "1464", 
"1467", "1470", "1475", "1476", "1477", "1479", "1481", "1482", 
"1484", "1486", "1488", "1489", "1490", "1491", "1492", "1499", 
"1500", "1501", "1502", "1505", "1509", "1511", "1513", "1515", 
"1517", "1518", "1520", "1525", "1533", "1538", "1539", "1542", 
"1543", "1549", "1550", "1553", "1554", "1558", "1561", "1568", 
"1571", "1572", "1574", "1575", "1578", "1579", "1581", "1583", 
"1586", "1590", "1593", "1595", "1597", "1600", "1603", "1604", 
"1608", "1613", "1615", "1616", "1617", "1619", "1620", "1621", 
"1622", "1624", "1629", "1633", "1635", "1637", "1638", "1639", 
"1649", "1651", "1652", "1653", "1658", "1659", "1660", "1661", 
"1666", "1674", "1675", "1680", "1682", "1687", "1689", "1691", 
"1693", "1694", "1695", "1699", "1700", "1701", "1702", "1703", 
"1706", "1707", "1710", "1712", "1713", "1714", "1716", "1717", 
"1718", "1719", "1721", "1723", "1727", "1728", "1729", "1730", 
"1732", "1733", "1734", "1735", "1737", "1740", "1744", "1750", 
"1751", "1753", "1755", "1757", "1759", "1760", "1762", "1766", 
"1770", "1773", "1774", "1775", "1777", "1778", "1779", "1782", 
"1784", "1787", "1790", "1796", "1799", "1801", "1808", "1809", 
"1810", "1811", "1812", "1813", "1814", "1818", "1819", "1820", 
"1821", "1822", "1824", "1827", "1830", "1833", "1834", "1835", 
"1837", "1841", "1844", "1853", "1854", "1857", "1858", "1860", 
"1863", "1867", "1868", "1871", "1872", "1876", "1879", "1881", 
"1883", "1884", "1886", "1890", "1891", "1892", "1893", "1897", 
"1898", "1900", "1902", "1904", "1905", "1906", "1910", "1912", 
"1913", "1917", "1918", "1919", "1920", "1921", "1922", "1923", 
"1924", "1925", "1926", "1927", "1929", "1930", "1931", "1933", 
"1935", "1936", "1939", "1941", "1942", "1945", "1949", "1954", 
"1955", "1957", "1964", "1965", "1966", "1970", "1973", "1974", 
"1975", "1976", "1978", "1979", "1984", "1985", "1987", "1988", 
"1993", "1994", "1996", "1997", "1999", "2000", "2002", "2004", 
"2005", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2017", "2018", "2022", 
"2024", "2026", "2027", "2030", "2031", "2032", "2033", "2035", 
"2036", "2037", "2039", "2040", "2044", "2047", "2048", "2049", 
"2051", "2053", "2054", "2056", "2057", "2059", "2063", "2064", 
"2065", "2066", "2067", "2069", "2071", "2073", "2075", "2077", 
"2078", "2082", "2083", "2088", "2089", "2090", "2092", "2096", 
"2097", "2099", "2100", "2109", "2110", "2113", "2114", "2116", 
"2117", "2119", "2120", "2121", "2125", "2127", "2128"), class = "factor"), 
    Study.Eye = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"), 
    Age = c(50L, 55L, 80L, 65L, 55L, 90L, 45L, 53L, 59L, 58L, 
    49L, 84L, 82L, 89L, 77L, 77L, 68L, 75L, 93L, 93L, 64L, 64L, 
    88L, 68L, 85L, 78L, 88L, 90L, 90L, 75L, 88L, 44L, 42L, 47L, 
    71L, 60L, 55L, 50L, 88L, 82L, 69L, 74L, 64L, 90L, 76L, 72L, 
    80L, 83L, 54L, 61L, 69L, 56L, 78L, 83L, 89L, 78L, 81L, 61L, 
    61L, 85L), Gender = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"), 
    Disease= c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
    1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 60L
), class = "data.frame")

example <- example %>% arrange(patient,Study.Eye)

geepack::geeglm(Disease~Age+Gender,family=binomial("logit"),id=patient,corstr="unstructured",data=example)


I get the following error message
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels

However, the same with an exchangeable correlation seems to run:
example <- example %>% arrange(patient,Study.Eye)

geepack::geeglm(Disease~Age+Gender,family=binomial("logit"),id=patient,corstr="exchangeable",data=example)


This is because you have a single measurement for some of your patients, which is issue for unstructured correlation.
Unstructured correlation structure estimates a unique correlation for each pair of observations within each cluster. If a cluster has only one observation, the correlation within that cluster cannot be estimated, leading to an error. If you had exactly 2 observations per patient, you would still have as many alphas as is the number of patients.
Exchangeable structure: assumes the same correlation across all pairs of observations within clusters. Only one correlation parameter (alpha) is estimated for all clusters (each cluster has the same alpha), so clusters with a single observation can still be included without issue

Thanks very much for the response! However, it is interesting that fitting the gee model in Stata using xtgee under both exchangeable and unstructured correlation structures yield identical results, in this case where clusters have at most 2 observations. Does this mean only a single parameter is being estimated for exchangeable and unstructured correlation structures in Stata, rather than as many alpha as is number of patients for the unstructured correlation. This is odd. Could this be an issue with the R package?
